# what does "-m" mean in UNIX ping command

Tags: linux, ping

I came across one UNIX ping command as such : 
`$for i in {1..30}; do ping -m $i -c 1 www.website.com; done`

What is the meaning of `-m` here? I have searched online and the only information I could find is that `-m` stands for "mark" and according to [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ping.8.html):

> use mark to tag the packets going out. This is useful for variety of
>   reasons within the kernel such as using policy routing to select
>   specific outbound processing.

I do not understand the explanation. I suspect that the command is trying to simulate something similar to `traceroute`. Can someone explain it in a more understandable way?

Comment: Why not ask this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows you to "mark" the a packet with a 32 bit value that you can later find with 'mark match'.

In your example '$for i in {1..30}; do ping -m $i -c 1 www.website.com; done' they are doing a ping to www.website.com and marking the ping packet with the value given to i. -c 1 means count 1 or ping once.

Reference is [HERE](http://andys.org.uk/bits/2010/01/27/iptables-fun-with-mark/)